# echo a conditional substring

Tags: php, if-statement, substring

I want to echo a conditional substring from:

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

The selector for my condition is " – "
If the selector exists in the string, I want to echo as a substring the part behind the selector. If the selector doesn't exist, I want to echo the full string.
Here is my idea, but I don't get it working:

```
if (($pos = strpos($data, " – ")) !== FALSE) {
$whatIWant = substr($data, $pos+1); 
}
echo $whatIWant; ?>
```

It is not working :-(
What should I change to echo the conditional substring?

Comment: whhere is $data?

Comment: That is a character encoding issue. Where did you get the dash you are using inside your strpos function? It does not equal the normal dash on my keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are very close, it is just the use of the `substr` that is incorrect

```
$whatIWant = $data;

if (($pos = strpos($data, " – ")) !== FALSE) {
    $whatIWant = substr($data, 0, $pos); 
}

echo $whatIWant;
```

Comment: Hmm, I was interpreting "behind the selector" to mean "to the right of"...

Comment: I can see how it can be interpreted that way, I just assumed the left based on that @Filz has a line that says `get_the_title()`, which makes me think the title of a webpage, and as such, kinda just want to get the left part, and also for the fact that though there is no syntax error on the user of substr, that it was not returning what @Filz wanted, which is the part to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct for the case where there's a dash. (Assuming that weird dash character is correct.) But you also have to consider the case where there's no dash. In that case, your code generates an empty string because $whatIWant is not initialized. If the string you want is the part to the right of the dash:

```
$pos = strpos($data, ' - ');
$whatIWant = substr($data, $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + 3);
echo $whatIWant;
```

If the string you want is to the left:

```
$pos = strpos($data, ' - ');
$whatIWant = $pos === false ? $data : substr($data, 0, $pos);
echo $whatIWant;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error was in $pos+1. When we code this, it works for me:

```
$data = "bye – hello";
$whatIWant = $data;
$search = " – ";
if (($pos = strpos($data, $search)) !== FALSE) {
    $whatIWant = substr($data, $pos+strlen($search)); 
}
echo $whatIWant;
```

Comment: Thank you. Helpful was also @Chip Dean I changed my search to " &#8211; " and it works.